# VBA Formula Referencing

Tags: vba, excel

I tried recording a formula in excel as a macro `=MAX(Q2:Q3)` which comes up in the VBA code as a R1C1 reference `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-1]:R[1]C[-1])"`

Is there any way I can input the formula in the VBA editor as the Excel reference rather than the R1C1 type of reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try to disable the R1C1 reference style from setting. I am not sure which version you are using.
I am using Mac OS, so for me it is something like Excel->Preferences->General->Use R1C1 reference style. Maybe I can check on some windows machine & confirm you, if it is same.

Regards,
Avdhesh

Answer (score 3):

The Excel MACRO recorder default setting is using the `FormulaR1C1`, just change to `Formula` and type the Range you need:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=MAX(Q2:Q3)"
```

In the future, if you want to use also the `Range` object, and allow yourself more flexibility, you can use something like the code below:

```
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Range("Q2:Q3")
ActiveCell.Formula = "=MAX(" & Rng.Address(False, False, xlA1) & ")"
```